# How can I color points on a scatterplot based on condition of two filters?

Tags: r, plot

I have a scatterplot and I would like to color points so that all points that meet the two conditions are red. Conditions are that `abs(x) > .15` and `abs(y)>1.4`

```
colour <- ifelse(abs(x)>.15, "red", "black")
colour <- ifelse(abs(y)>1.4, "red", "black")
# colour <- ifelse((abs(y)>1.4&&abs(x)>.15), "red", "black") #all black
plot(y, x, main="scatter - meth vs exp - diff", xlab="delta beta (.15)", ylab="log2(exp)", col=colour)
abline(h=c(-1.4, 1.4), v=c(-.15, .15), col="gray", lty=3)
```

What am I missing here? Appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: `ifelse((abs(x)>.15) & (abs(y)>1.4), "red", "black")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this produce the desired result?

```
x <- rnorm(10)
y <- rnorm(10)
colour <- ifelse(abs(x)>.15 & abs(y)>1.4, "red", "black")
# colour <- ifelse((abs(y)>1.4&&abs(x)>.15), "red", "black") #all black
plot(y, x, main="scatter - meth vs exp - diff", xlab="delta beta (.15)", ylab="log2(exp)", col=colour)
abline(h=c(-1.4, 1.4), v=c(-.15, .15), col="gray", lty=3)
```

Just combine the two conditions using `&`.